# Smack API delete specific offline message

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, openfire, smack

Currently the issue im facing in using SMACK API and Openfire is that after i retrieve offline chat messages from the server with OfflineMessageManager, i can't remove the specific message.

i uses this method to get the node for the message, where offlineMessage is an arrayList that holds all the offline message that i retrieve. Thos node will be saved in another arrayList named stamps.

```
((OfflineMessageInfo)offlineMessages.get(i)).getNode();
```

And this is the part that I execute the offline message delection code

```
omm.deleteMessages(stamps);
```

But when i run getMessageCount, all my offlineMessage is still there, none gets removed, so i browse [the method](https://github.com/mar-v-in/XMPP-for-Android/blob/8c62f24245a81aa6c191967daf414640c51568ca/src/org/jivesoftware/smackx/OfflineMessageManager.java) to see am i missing something. As i log the packet i send and respond i receive, is exactly same as mention on [this website](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0013.html#remove-specific).

As the reason why i need to remove only specific message but not all is because there might be new incoming message while I downloading offline messages and my presence is not set to available yet. If i choose to delete all, those new message will be gone. If i didn't remove it, once i set presence to online, those message that i had retrieve will flood and cause duplicate.

Edited :
Just now i did some more testing including passing a null/random character node and the server still giving the exact same response

```
06-26 15:00:53.276: D/debugger(24069): response : <iq id="remove_test" to="someone@something.com/Smack" type="result"></iq>
```

Will this be a server side issue ?

Comment: Sorry for jumping in..But can you point me to any good tutorial for setting up ASMACK and Openfire. I've been wanting to learn this since a long time !

Comment: I learn part of it from a [china website](http://www.apkbus.com/home.php?mod=space&uid=125132&do=blog&id=52801) .But part of the method doesn't work due to some weird error, so I've also did some trial and error by referring to [Smack GitHub](https://github.com/rtreffer/smack/blob/bf8516ae76464b9615332f34989e706b7660b83d/source/org/jivesoftware/smackx/OfflineMessageManager.java). As for server side I afraid i can't help you on that because I was not in charge of setting up the chat server, i only involve in Smack API part.